# По какому принципу "переводят" передают имена в документах Белоруссии и Украины с русского и наоборот украинском и белорусских паспортах и сор

Tags: ономастика

Объясните пожалуйста как "переводят" имена людей в документах Белоруссии и Украины, например имя Елена записывают я так понимаю аналогом Олена[Олэна] или транскрипцией Єлена, но ведь аналог Олена это другое имя, и уже не звучит как Елена по русски , хотя в разговоре они наверное ВСЕ ЕЛЕНЫ или Олэна это и есть Олэна. И в Беларуси есть имя АлЕна через Е так и произносится, это не Алёна, а в разговоре они кто? Елена или АлЕна? Вообще запутался, извините за такой вопрос я не очень в ономастике разбираюсь. Кстати в Белоруссии есть и Ялена, и Ялена намного логичнее чем Алена через Е с первоначальным А. Ведь там Якают первоначальное Е заменяют на Я. Если можно подробнее и попроще объясните. Если не ошибаюсь то в Беларуси паспорт на двух государственных языках а в Украине только на мове записывают сейчас. И есть ли в русском языке такие формы как имя АлЕна через Е произношение(белорусское имя) или например Олэна(украинская форма имени)? Например на русской странице паспорта Белоруси пишут Елена а на белорусской странице пишут Алена, то кто она в разговоре Елена или АлЕна(через Е)? Благодарю заранее!

Comment: В случае, если заявитель желает изменить написание фамилии и (или) имени в новом заграничном паспорте предоставляется заявление (произвольной формы) об изменении написания фамилии и (или) имени, в котором должна быть указана причина, являющаяся основанием для изменения написания фамилии и (или) имени, с приложением одного из подтверждающих документов

Comment: Верность перевода и подлинность подписи переводчика должны быть нотариально засвидетельствованы в соответствии с законодательством Российской Федерации о нотариате – в соответствии с требованием пунктов 44, 45 Административного регламента, утвержденного приказом МВД России от 27.11.2017 № 889, и пункта 43 Административного регламента, утвержденного приказом МВД России от 16.11.2017 № 864. https://62.мвд.рф/ms/uvm-pr/item/18256316/

Comment: https://otvet.mail.ru/question/35475058 пишу на опыте своего ребенка, я-русская, папа-голландец. 
паспорта/гражданства у ребенка - 2! 
в русский паспорт очества не записывается.... он родился здесь, в свидетельстве о рождении все его данные указаны, ВСЕ дописывать больше ничего нельзя :) 
... 
кстати с иностранцев которые в Россию захотят переехать жить тоже очества выдумывать не требуют ;)

Comment: Депардьё Жерар Ксавие - паспорт фото, хотя везде в сми его фамилию пишут как Депардье. https://economic-definition.com/Images/Forex_Otzovik/250/450/1114119681-grazhdanstvo.jpg

Comment: Вообще то вопрос был про другое но всё равно спасибо

Comment: Переводят по правилам русского языка, в остальных случаях нужно нотариально завереное заявление о переводе ФИО в соответствии с др документами вроде свидетельства о рождении и тп.  Отчество обычно не делают если его нет, но могут сделать. Нет никаких особых проблем в корректировке имени.